# Hard drive not recognized in Ubuntu 12.04 install

Tags: ubiquity

I don't know how to fix it the computer has no hard drive.I'm trying to install Ubuntu for the computer onto my external hard drive and none of the buttons are working.

[image]

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

just to make it clear for me: You want to install Ubuntu on a external disk for using it as a boot hdd later?
If so You will have to install it on the external drive the following:
- chose the correct drive in the drag down menu (there where "/dev/sda" is shown in the picture) and chose "sdb" instead if possible.
if not please write or show me, what else is listed up there.

- if you have chosen the external HD correctly you have to do three things

  1. create the partition for the root system - recommended is something from 20 GB on, as far as I know
  2. create the partition for the SWAP - recommended 2.5 times your RAM but if the RAM is >/= 4GB then 2 times is enough so 8GB if the RAM is 4GB
  3. create a "Data" partition for your precious files.
     after having done this the Installer should be able to go on.

Comment: So would it work if I got ubunto on my flashdrive and wiped my external hard drive and the install ubunto from the flash drive onto the external hard drive?

Comment: Lol. Never mind I awnserd my own question.